# Issue with Normal Inverse Gamma

Tags: matlab

I Tried to implement Normal Inverse Gamma function using matalb but iam getting error.

```
function [ INGN ] = inversegamNormpdf(X,A,B,L,U,S )

INGN=(sqrt(L)/S*sqrt(2*pi))*(B^A/gamma(A))*((1/S^2)^A+1)*exp(-2*B+L*(X-U)^2/2*S^2);

end
```

then calling function as
where x is data which composed of 260*4.

```
INGN  = inversegamNormpdf(x,A,B,L,U,S );
```

i do not know how to solve it ?

Comment: What's the specific error? What are the values of the  other parameters? Could any of them be causing the problem? We need more to go on.

Comment: Does "where x is data which composed of 260*4" mean that `x` is a 260-by-4 matrix? You're going to need to use element-wise operators, e.g., `(X-U).^2`

Comment: Thanks , but i have another question the results are four value ? if i multiply it by p which is 260X1 by the  4 value  i am getting 260X4 ? i should have 260 X1 value .?? for i=1:sizeX
INGN = inversegamNormpdf(x(i,:),A,B,L,U,S ); end